# 3120 error from ReceivePaymentAddRq - php devkit

Tags: quickbooks

I'm adding receive payments using php devkit here https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php.

The problem is no response from the quickbooks and also there is no issue. I checked the web connector logs and php log files. 
But response function is not called ever.

I'm pretty sure this was working well until few days ago. 
I have no idea what the exact problem is.

**qbxml version: 10.0**

**request xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="10.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
        <ReceivePaymentAddRq requestID="153">
            <ReceivePaymentAdd>
                <CustomerRef >
                    <FullName >Duncan, Dave</FullName>
                </CustomerRef>
                <TxnDate >2023-12-15</TxnDate>
                <RefNumber>Wire</RefNumber>
                <TotalAmount>2585.00</TotalAmount>
                <PaymentMethodRef><FullName>Check</FullName></PaymentMethodRef>
                <Memo>Paid In Full</Memo>
                <AppliedToTxnAdd>
                    <TxnID>28CA9-1702576301</TxnID>
                    <PaymentAmount >2585.00</PaymentAmount>
                </AppliedToTxnAdd>
            </ReceivePaymentAdd>
        </ReceivePaymentAddRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

**php scripts:**

```
$map = array(
QUICKBOOKS_ADD_RECEIVE_PAYMENT => array( '_quickbooks_payment_add_request', '_quickbooks_payment_add_response' ));

$errmap = array(
        // QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_CUSTOMER => '_quickbooks_customer_query_error', 
        '*' => '_quickbooks_error_catchall',                // Catch any other errors that might occur
..

$hooks = array(
        QuickBooks_WebConnector_Handlers::HOOK_LOGINSUCCESS => '_quickbooks_sync_to_qb',    // call this whenever a successful login occurs
    );
```

```
function _quickbooks_sync_to_qb($requestID, $user, $hook, &$err, $hook_data, $callback_config)
{ 
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();

    $Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($database->dsn);
    $payment = new Payment($db);
    $payment->needSync = true; 

    $stmt = $payment->read();
    $num = $stmt->rowCount();

    if ($num > 0) {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_RECEIVE_PAYMENT, $row['id']);
        }
    }


    $database->destroy();
}
```

```
function _quickbooks_payment_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{error_log('start from here');
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();

    // Grab the data from our MySQL database
    $payment = new Payment($db);
    $payment->id = (int) $ID;
    error_log('1');
    // Validation
    $stmt = $payment->read();
    $num = $stmt->rowCount();

    if ($num > 0) {error_log('2');
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            extract($row);

            // get trasaction id from invoice
            $invoice = new Invoice($db);
            $invoice->refNumber = $invoice_ref_number;
            error_log('21');
            $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <?qbxml version="10.0"?>
                <QBXML>
                    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
                        <ReceivePaymentAddRq>
                            <ReceivePaymentAdd>';

                    if ($customer_ref_listid != '' || $customer_ref_fullname != '') {

                        $xml .= '<CustomerRef >';

                        if ($customer_ref_listid != '') {

                            $xml .= '<ListID  >' . $customer_ref_listid . '</ListID>';

                            // invoice customer ref listid
                            $invoice->customerRefListID = $customer_ref_listid;
                        }
                        if ($customer_ref_fullname != '') {

                            $xml .= '<FullName >' . $customer_ref_fullname . '</FullName>';

                            // invoice customer ref fullname
                            $invoice->customerRefFullName = $customer_ref_fullname;
                        }

                        $xml .= '</CustomerRef>';
                    }


                    $stmt = $invoice->read();
                    $num = $stmt->rowCount();
                    $txnID = '';
                    $txnDate = '';

                    if ($num > 0) {

                        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                            $txnID = $row['txn_id'];
                            $txnDate = date_format(date_create($row['txn_date']), 'Y-m-d');

                        }
                    }


                        $xml .= '<TxnDate >' . $txnDate . '</TxnDate>
                                <RefNumber>' . $ref_number . '</RefNumber>
                                <TotalAmount>' . $total_amount . '</TotalAmount>
                                <PaymentMethodRef>';

                        if (!empty($payment_method_ref_listid)) {

                            $xml .= '<ListID>' . $payment_method_ref_listid . '</FullName>';
                        }
                        if (!empty($payment_method_ref_fullname)) {

                            $xml .= '<FullName>' . $payment_method_ref_fullname . '</FullName>';
                        }

                        $xml .= '</PaymentMethodRef>
                                <Memo>' . $memo . '</Memo>
                                <AppliedToTxnAdd>
                                    <TxnID>' . $txnID . '</TxnID>
                                    <PaymentAmount >' . $total_amount . '</PaymentAmount>
                                </AppliedToTxnAdd>
                            </ReceivePaymentAdd>
                        </ReceivePaymentAddRq>
                    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                </QBXML>';
                error_log('22');
        }
        error_log('3');
        $database->destroy();
        error_log('4');
        error_log($xml);
        return $xml;
    }
    error_log('5');
    $database->destroy();
    return false;

}
```

**This function seems not called even it is registered properly.**

```
function _quickbooks_payment_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{error_log('_quickbooks_payment_add_response');
    $database = new Database();
```

**EDIT:**
**VERBOSE LOG**

```
20190327.20:42:17 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : qbNationality="US"
20190327.20:42:17 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : qbXMLMajorVers="13"
20190327.20:42:17 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : qbXMLMinorVers="0"
20190327.20:42:17 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : Received from sendRequestXML() following parameter:
20190327.20:42:17 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : strRequestXML =
20190327.20:42:17 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : XML dump follows: -

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <?qbxml version="10.0"?>
                <QBXML>
                    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
                        <ReceivePaymentAddRq requestID="158">
                            <ReceivePaymentAdd><CustomerRef ><FullName >Duncan, Dave</FullName></CustomerRef><RefNumber>Wire</RefNumber>
                                <TotalAmount>2585.00</TotalAmount>
                                <PaymentMethodRef><FullName>Check</FullName></PaymentMethodRef>
                                <Memo>Paid In Full</Memo>
                                <AppliedToTxnAdd>
                                    <TxnID>28CA9-1702576301</TxnID>
                                    <PaymentAmount >2585.00</PaymentAmount>
                                </AppliedToTxnAdd>
                            </ReceivePaymentAdd>
                        </ReceivePaymentAddRq>
                    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                </QBXML>

20190327.20:42:17 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : Request xml received.
20190327.20:42:17 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Processing request #1
20190327.20:42:17 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : REQUEST: received from application: size (bytes) = 666
20190327.20:42:17 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Sending request to QuickBooks.
20190327.20:42:17 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Response received from QuickBooks: size (bytes) = 245
20190327.20:42:17 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Sending response back to application.
20190327.20:42:17 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : *** Calling receiveResponseXML() with following parameters:
20190327.20:42:17 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : wcTicket="35382423-f97d-5fc4-3935-d4a7629367a8"
20190327.20:42:17 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : response =
20190327.20:42:17 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : XML dump follows: -

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRs>
<ReceivePaymentAddRs requestID="158" statusCode="3120" statusSeverity="Error" statusMessage="Object &quot;28CA9-1702576301&quot; specified in the request cannot be found. " />
</QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>


20190327.20:42:17 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : hresult=""
20190327.20:42:17 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : message=""
20190327.20:42:17 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : Received from receiveResponseXML() following parameters:
20190327.20:42:17 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : more="100">
20190327.20:42:17 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : Done. No more to process.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the logs (Web Connector logs in `VERBOSE` mode and also the `quickbooks_log` SQL table output) exactly what's wrong here, but here's at least a few things to check:

**1. Are you SURE you're not getting a response from QuickBooks?**

You indicate "The problem is no response from the quickbooks" but that may not be the actual case here.

Have you verified that you're not getting a response in the actual logs? For example, if an *error were to occur* (e.g. maybe the customer or the invoice does not exist) then QuickBooks will send back an error *but your response function won't get called -- an error handler will get called instead*.

Do you have something like this in your code?

```
$errmap = array(
    3070 => '_quickbooks_error_stringtoolong',              // Whenever a string is too long to fit in a field, call this function: _quickbooks_error_stringtolong()
    // ... more error handlers here ...
    );
```

(from https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector.php )

Maybe an error handler is getting called instead of your response function?

**2. You aren't passing a requestID="..." attribute**

The Web Connector uses a `requestID="..."` attribute in the XML to be able to match up the outgoing requests with the incoming responses. You're not using it, but should be.

Change this:

`<ReceivePaymentAddRq>`

To this:

`<ReceivePaymentAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">`

Read more:

- http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_php_consolibyte#i_m_getting_the_error_messageno_registered_functions_for_action

**3. You're not XML encoding values**

For this:

`<Memo>' . $memo . '</Memo>`

If `$memo` is set to `bla bla <something> bla bla` then you're going to end up with malformed XML:

`<Memo>bla bla <something bla bla</Memo>`

You should be XML-encoding these values.

**4. The $memo variable is undefined**

You're saying that your resulting XML looks like this:

`<Memo>Paid In Full</Memo>`

But when I look at your code, `$memo` is *undefined*. This makes me suspect that the XML you pasted here is *not* the actual XML you're sending to QuickBooks.

Where does that variable get set to `Paid In Full`? It doesn't get set anywhere in the code you pasted.

This should also be causing a PHP error/warning about an undefined variable, which could be breaking things.

**5. Make sure your Web Connector is in VERBOSE mode**

VERBOSE mode in the Web Connector shows a lot more data. You should be able to easily find the request in question and analyze/post the relevant logs.

**6. Check the quickbooks_log and quickbooks_queue tables**

What do they show/say?

What is the status (`qb_status` field) and message on the queued up record (`quickbooks_queue` SQL table)?

Comment: I checked _queue table, qb_status says "h" and msg field is "3120: Object "28CA9-1702576301" specified in the request cannot be found. "

Comment: FYI, I added the requsetID to the qbxml and the above xml is coming from the log file which means $memo is not undefined, the problem is 3120 error code

Comment: Ah, so you ARE getting a response from QuickBooks then! I will amend my answer with some additional details here.

Comment: I checked the invoice and trasaction ID "28CA9-1702576301", this is correct one. I'm not sure why the log says this - "Attempting to handle error: 3120, Object "28CA9-1702576301" specified in the request cannot be found.". after request, it falls into catch error function because of this issue.

Comment: Is the invoice paid or unpaid? Is the balance on the invoice less than or equal to the amount you are applying to it? Is the customer for the invoice the same as the customer for the payment? Is the A/R account for the payment the same as the A/R account for the invoice? I'd start with those.

Comment: Yeah invoice is not paid yet and payment amount is exact same with the invoice, no tax. and customer is same. I'm not sue about a/r account. I'm going to edit the question with the verbose log file

Comment: Thanks, Keith. It's working again. I have changed the qbxml version to 10 (original was 2) added requestID attribute to the ReceivePaymentAddRq and the last one is transaction date field (was used same date with the invoice). I'm not sure what was the exact issue btw it is working now.